# Assigning values from grouping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, assign

I have a question that I cant resolve. Lets see if you can help me.

I have this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(7, 4)),columns=['ONE', 'TWO', 'NAMES', 'FOUR'],index = fechas)
df['NAMES'] = ['Peter','Jon',' Mary','Mary','Peter','Peter','Mary']
```

Suppose that I want to group by names in col names and once I've done this I want to assign the values of col 1 to col 2 by the groups recently done, following the criteria  that I have to assign the value of the element in col 1 to the whole  group by name that has the first 0 in col 4

This is what I got

```
            ONE  TWO  NAMES  FOUR
1970-01-01    0    0  Peter     0
1970-01-02    2    1    Jon     0
1970-01-03    1    0   Mary     0
1970-01-04    1    1   Mary     0
1970-01-05    0    2  Peter     1
1970-01-06    2    2  Peter     0
1970-01-07    0    0   Mary     1
```

And I need something like this:

```
            ONE  TWO  NAMES  FOUR
1970-01-01    0    0  Peter     0
1970-01-02    2    1    Jon     0
1970-01-03    1    1   Mary     0
1970-01-04    1    1   Mary     0
1970-01-05    0    0  Peter     1
1970-01-06    2    0  Peter     0
1970-01-07    0    1   Mary     1
```

I hope it is all well explained. 
Thank you

Comment: I have a huge df, and I want to make groups by the values of one column.  Then I want to check which of that elements from the groups has a 60000 in another column, thats is going to be the "father" that will pass his value from another third column to another fourth column.  It is hard to explain

Comment: if it's hard to explain, then you're not ready to ask the question on SO yet.

Comment: @jezrael  just got the logic, but his code doesnt work well at all.

Comment: SO isn't a guessing game where you describe a problem vaguely and then whoever comes closest to what you're intending wins a prize.

Comment: Its not my intention to waster your time mate, I really cant explain it better.  Really sorry and thanks for reading it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need first filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) all rows with `0` in column `FOUR` and then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by `NAMES` column with keep first value. Then convert to `dict` columns `NAMES` as key and `ONE` as value and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'ONE': [0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0], 
'TWO': [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0], 
'NAMES': ['Peter', 'Jon', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Mary'], 
'FOUR': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]})
df = df[['ONE', 'TWO', 'NAMES', 'FOUR']]
print (df)
   ONE  TWO  NAMES  FOUR
0    0    0  Peter     0
1    2    1    Jon     0
2    1    0   Mary     0
3    1    1   Mary     0
4    0    2  Peter     1
5    2    2  Peter     0
6    0    0   Mary     1
```

```
print (df[df.FOUR == 0].drop_duplicates(['NAMES']))
   ONE  TWO  NAMES  FOUR
0    0    0  Peter     0
1    2    1    Jon     0
2    1    0   Mary     0

d = df[df.FOUR == 0].drop_duplicates(['NAMES']).set_index('NAMES')['ONE'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'Jon': 2, 'Mary': 1, 'Peter': 0}

df.TWO = df.NAMES.map(d)
print (df)
            ONE  TWO  NAMES  FOUR
1970-01-01    0    0  Peter     0
1970-01-02    2    2    Jon     0
1970-01-03    1    1   Mary     0
1970-01-04    1    1   Mary     0
1970-01-05    0    0  Peter     1
1970-01-06    2    0  Peter     0
1970-01-07    0    1   Mary     1
```

Comment: I think value `Jon` in column `TWO` is `2`, because in column `FOUR` is first `0`.

Comment: That doenst work well mate.                                                                                                                                    ONE  TWO  NAMES  FOUR
1970-01-01    0  0.0  Peter     0
1970-01-02    2  2.0    Jon     0
1970-01-03    2  2.0   Mary     0
1970-01-04    2  NaN   Mary     2
1970-01-05    2  0.0  Peter     1
1970-01-06    2  0.0  Peter     0
1970-01-07    0  NaN   Mary    1    Note that the second and third Mary should have a 2.0 in col 2 although Peter's group works well.

Comment: Thankls for your help, I am gonna check again. @jezrael

Comment: I think problem is `randint` because you get still different output if run code. Better is use `np.random.seed(123)` for testing for same output.

Comment: Ok, now I do understand your solution, it might work. The thing is that in my real case all the groups of names are going to have  a 0 . Thank you

Comment: If all values in column `FOUR` are `0`, then simply remove `boolean indexing` and solution is simplier `df.drop_duplicates(['NAMES']).set_index('NAMES')['ONE'].to_dict()`